# How to add a scope for multiple enums in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, enums, scope

I have a select that displays all enums of an object:

```
<%= f.select( :state_user 
            , User.states.keys.map {|state| [state.titleize,state] }) %>
```

How can I create an scope that allows me to select multiple states?

For example I want to filter all users that are either inactive or suspended.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got it working with this scope:

```
 scope :state, lambda { |enum_ids|
  return nil  if enum_ids.empty?
    objArray = []
    enum_ids.each do |key|
      if (User.estados[key])
        objArray << User.estados[key] 
      end
    end
    return nil  if objArray.empty?
    where (["account.state in (?)" ,  objArray])
 }
```

Answer (score 8):

Not sure if you're still looking for something like this but here's what I found.

### Solution

I was able to implement this using the following

```
scope :for_states, -> (*state_names) {
  where(state: states.values_at(*Array(state_names).flatten))
}
```

The `*state_names` argument will allow any number of arguments to get packaged up into a `state_names` array. `Array(state_names)` ensures that this if a single argument was passed it will be treated as an array. Finally, `flatten` allows a single array to be passed as an argument. After all that, the splat (`*`) unpacks all elements of this array as arguments to the `values_at` method.

You can use this as follows:

1. `User.for_states :one_state`
2. `User.for_states :state_1, :state_2`
3. `User.for_states [:state_1, :state_2]`

If you don't need the method to be as flexible, it could be simplified.

### The Future

According to the [Edge Rails Docs](http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Enum.html) this should be even simpler in Rails 5 and you'll simply be able to do

```
User.where(state: [:state_1, :state_2])
```